# Is it possible to Host Provider Hosted APP in Dedicated Server IIS and Consume in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app

We need to setup provider hosted app in dedicated server and consume in Office 365. Is it possible?

If yes, then how we can take "ClientContext" to read/write operation to Office 365 Web list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , It can be done by following the steps we used to do with High Trusted Apps Deployment(Server to Server) in On Premises ,

```
Self signed certificate for your web app in local IIS
Register app using appregnew.aspx
Use the client secret and ID in the web.config
```

Please refer this for detailed info on this topic:  https://bishwadebdey.blogspot.com/2016/01/step-by-step-creation-of-provider.html?showComment=1486621176030#c1394076155011092551

Comment: Hi... When I am deploying my app to Office 365 with Office 365 AppRegNew and respective web.config I am not able to take ClientContext object.


In above link they are not using ClientContext.  I am able to open site but I need to do operation further.

Comment: we can get the clientcontext like this:  var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
var hostWeb = Page.Request[“SPHostUrl”];

using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithContextToken(hostWeb, contextToken, Request.Url.Authority))
{
 clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title, user => user.CurrentUser);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 }

Comment: While using above code ClientContex not getting "OAuth2AccessTokenResponse" from TokelHelper class file which is provider by Microsoft. Can you elaborate this reason?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. I worked on a provider hosted add-in which I deployed in IIS and was used by O365. When you create the add-in, give O365 site URL and log in. After that select SP Online as `earliest version of SP that you want your app to target`. Next you can select `Web Forms` or `MVC` according to your wish and use `Windows Azure Access Control Service (for SP cloud apps)`

Now you can deploy the app wherever you want. Give URL of IIS website while publishing and make the domain public.

I am not going into detailed steps as you will find many links on internet like 
[this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2014/06/26/part-2-intro-to-provider-hosted-apps-develop-package-and-deploy/)

Regarding, `ClientContext` use it in the same way as you will find in demo code which comes after the project is created. No difference.

Hope this helps!